# want to replace categoryId with category name

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I have two tables in database

**category table** that contain (`categoryId` ,`categoryName`)

**product table** that contain (`productId`,`productName`,`price`,`categoryId`)

I have retrieve product table in jsp page like that ,but I want to replace `categoryId` with `category name`

```
  <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
   <tr>
      <td>${p.productName}</td>
      <td>${p.price}</td>
      <td>${p.categoryId}</td>    // want to replace categoryId with category name here
      </tr>
  <c:forEach>
```

Comment: show your entity, inside `Product` entity it is just `Long categoryId` or reference of `category class`

Comment: Get category name from category id and display it, seems no problem here.

Comment: Long categoryId - ankur-singhal

Comment: @user3498071 either keep the reference for `category ` inside `Product` or load the `Category Name` from ID

Comment: How to load the Category Name from Id?

Comment: you have to hit the DB to get the name for the given ID, nothing special

Answer (score 1):

You should have a bi-directional `@OneToMany` relationship between your `Category` and `Product` entities.

Once you load all the `Product's` the `Category` will also get loaded if you set the fetching strategy to `JOIN`. Now if you pass your products to your jsp then you can access the category name like this:

```
${p.category.categoryName}
```

Comment: I don't have relationship just I add Long categoryId to product table

Comment: In that case you are not using Hibernate properly, as per your question the Category & Product entities are related to each other. If you don't want to maintain the relationship then you need to handle it yourself, like get the category name for the given category id and then create a map that takes category id as key and category name as value. Then you can get the map in JSP and get the category name from the map for the given categroy id.